# How to fix function plot not showing derivative

Tags: javascript, function, math, graph, derivative

i was trying to make a function graph plotting app using javascript's function plot library so it worked well when it was in code but when i added inputs from the html code and linked them to the properties of functionPlot(), it actually worked first time when there were just the function eqaution and graph color inputs, but when i added derivative input it didnt work and the graph was all the way frozen (can't move it or zoom and doesn't show the derivative when you hover the mouse) so i'm going to leave the code here so you can see it and help me

Javascript:

```
var parameters = {
    target: '#myFunction',
    width: '810',
    height: '540',
    data: [{
      fn: '', 
      color: '',
      derivative: {
        fn: '',
        updateOnMouseMove: true
      }
   }],
    grid: true,
    yAxis: {domain: [-9, 9]},
    xAxis: {domain: [-7, 7]}
  };

  function plot() {
    var f = document.querySelector("#function").value;
    var color = document.querySelector("#color").value;
    var derivative = document.querySelector("#der").value;

    parameters.data[0].fn = f;
    parameters.data[0].color = color;
    parameters.data[0].derivative.fn = derivative;
    functionPlot(parameters);
  };
```

HTML:

```
    <body onload="plot();">
  <h2>Function plotter</h2>
  <div class="layer">
  <section id="plotSettings">

    <p></p>
    <label for="color">Color: </label> value: <input type=color id="color" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <label for="function">Function to plot: </label>
    <input id="function" type="text" value="" onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <label for="derivative">derivative: </label> 
    <input type=text id="der", value="", onchange="plot();">
    <p></p>
    <button onclick="plot();">Plot it!</button>

  </section>

  <section id="plot">
    <div id="myFunction"></div>
  </section>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope you have understood my problem
thanks

Comment: You're calling `plot()` before there are any functions in the fields, which apparently messes up the library: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/n8pe49j2/

Comment: but it works when i delete the derivative input and var definition

Comment: Ohh thanks man you made my day